# Radio Button List value is showing null when I am assigning in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

Error is showing

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

at `rdb5.SelectedValue = "1"` and going to catch block. Data is coming right and going inside the loop but error is showing at `rdb5.SelectedValue = "1"`.

```
RadioButtonList rdb5 = (RadioButtonList)e.Row.FindControl("rdb5");
RadioButtonList rdb6 = (RadioButtonList)e.Row.FindControl("rdb6");
RadioButtonList rdb7 = (RadioButtonList)e.Row.FindControl("rdb7");
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConStr1"]))
{

    string sql = "select * from RateSchedule ";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adpt.Fill(ds);
    string s = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["RegularLabor"].ToString().Trim();

    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["TaskType"].ToString() == "Default")
    {

    }
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["RegularLabor"].ToString().Trim() == "True")
    {
        rdb5.SelectedValue = "1";
        //Here it is showing error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
    }
    else
    {
        rdb5.SelectedValue = "2";
    }
```

Comment: It showing error becuase `rdb5` is null, not found in method and if try to access null control property this will give `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error

Comment: How to overcome this problem?

Comment: You need to make sure that `rdb5` control exists in gridview. so need to check correct id to find control.

Comment: But it is already  there in gridview.

Comment: Also can you make sure if `rdb5` control have options filled and have option with value `1` or `2`

Comment: <asp:ListItem Value="1">Y</asp:ListItem>
                                                                                <asp:ListItem Value="2">N</asp:ListItem>

Comment: Given In Girdview